# No puedo recibir el JSON en una llamada a la API de Steam

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

estoy trabajando en una app de React.js que tiene como objetivo poder buscar un juego que esté en steam y mostrar información de ese juego.

El problema es que cuando hago la llamada por fetch a esta url:
https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/

no logro que me retorne ninguna data,
sin embargo si esta llamada la hago por Postman la respuesta es exitosa

```
fetch( 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/', {
      'mode': 'no-cors',   
})
      .then( resp => resp.json())
      .then( data => {
            console.log(data);
      })
```

Puse el

```
'mode': 'no-cors',
```

porque sino me tira el siguiente error en la consola:
*Access to fetch at 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

Comment: Manuel, para que alguien te ayude tenes que colocar el codigo que estas usando para realizar la llamada, yo copie la url en el navegador y veo un json, entonces el conflicto esta en tu codigo

Comment: No recibes ningún dato precisamente por el `no-cors`. Esa propiedad hace que el navegador no deje pasar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que steam no permite llamadas desde clientes, tendrás que crear un servidor, por ejemplo un nodejs con express y que dicho servidor sea quien llama a la api y tu desde el cliente deberás llamar a tu servidor.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!